# WordPress Language Files editor

Tags: wordpress

Guys I need to edit wordpress language file editor . The file format is .mo . I tried to edit poedit the file but . doesn't work . Please give me any suggestion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For poedit, you need the .po file, not the .mo one.  If you mean the main WordPress translation, you can download the .po file from subversion.  For example:

http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/fr_FR/branches/3.9/messages/fr_FR.po

Though it'd be worth checking that a translation doesn't already exist for your language.

Comment: Thank You . But I can't find the .po file. Can you give me any link of .po file??

Comment: Um, there's a link to a .po file in my answer.  If you drop the file name (http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/fr_FR/branches/3.9/messages/) you'll be able to browse the subversion repo and hopefully find the file you need.

Comment: You're welcome.  If my answer solved your problem can you accept it (click the check mark next to it) and/or vote it up?  If it didn't, what else do you need?

Comment: Actually I am newbie here . I don't know How can do it . Can you tell me ?? how do you vote your answer ?